# Trying to wget.download from list of URLs with for loop in python, but after 150 images it just freezes. (no error message)

Tags: python, url, download, wget

I have an issue, where I try to download list of URLs with for loop and wget.download. But after certain amount of downloaded images it just stops downloading. (no error message) and the script keeps running until I stop it manually.

I tried to use try, except - pass/continue

```
import wget
import os

fileName = os.listdir('data')
print(fileName)
for x in fileName:
 print(x)
 os.mkdir(x + ' - img')
 lineList = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('data/' + x)]
 for y in lineList:
    print(y)
    wget.download(y, out=x + '.jpg')
```

I expect the script to create a new folder. Then open files and load lines into list and then loop through the list and download all URLs
[screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBv0R.png)

Comment: It sounds like the remote server decided you're a bot and is deliberately not serving any more images to you.

Comment: This can happen even if the URLs are from completely different sites?

Comment: Oh, I assumed they were all on the same site.  If they're all different, then this likely isn't the cause.

Comment: The last bit of the script seems to have incorrect indentation.  The final `for` is indented when it shouldn't be, and the lines underneath it aren't indented when they should be.

Comment: I added screenshot from PyCharm as it was almost impossible for me to input the code in the question. But as I want to run the second loop in the first loop it should be right under the lineList= right? https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBv0R.png